# WiFi not working in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I have issues with my WiFi driver on my Acer E5 575G notebook.
I have tried to install drivers manually and I have even tried to `apt install firmware-realtek` and `apt install firmware-atheros`
I have even tried to manually install drivers from git but with no luck.

Useful information:

```
neisor@debianneisor:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1904 (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1916 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d31 (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d60 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d03 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d48 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 179c (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)

neisor@debianneisor:~$ uname -a
Linux debianneisor 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@debianneisor:/home/neisor# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release:        8.7
Codename:       jessie
```

Just to make things clear, my ethernet adapter works but my WiFi doesn't. Another thing, my WiFi has always worked out-of-the-box in Fedora and Ubuntu.

Any idea on how to fix it on Debian?

Thank you.

Comment: "I have tried to install drivers manually and I even tried to  apt install firmware-realtek and apt install firmware-atheros" What happened when you tried this? What EXACT error messages did you get? Has your sources list been changed to add "non-free"? Have you Rebooted?

Comment: please, post the output of `dmesg`

Comment: @arocheste No errors were shown, everything installed just fine but the functionality did not come to life. Yes, I added the non-free repository too in the sources.list.

Comment: @mattia.b89 dmesg is shown here http://pastebin.com/ifr0snhG

Hope it helps :) Thank you

Comment: Suggestion that it works with an updated kernel. Install Stretch Debian instead? https://digitz.org/blog/wifi-issue-on-acer-laptops-running-linux-qualcomm-atheros-device-0042/

Comment: Already tried the suggestions provided in the link, didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ath10k` driver isn't available on debian jessie , you should get it from backports .

Add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Search and Install a new kernel from backports:

```
apt-cache search linux-image
apt-get install linux-image-xxx
apt-get install linux-headers-xxx
```

Reboot then install the [`firmware-atheros`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/firmware-atheros) from backports:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-atheros
modprobe ath10k
```